# Error TDBXTypes.DOUBLE con Delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2008, delphi-2010

tengo este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No puedo resolverlo, busque en muchos foros pero mo logro encontrar una solucion.
Estoy desarrollando en delphi un programa cliente -servidor con datasnap.
Este error aparece cuando ejecuto un procedimiento INSERT en sqlserver:
Script del lado del cliente:

```
    var client : TTServerMethodsClient;
    var ds:TDataset;
    var dst:TDataset;
    var ch : char;
    var canti : String;
    var eproceso : String;
    var suma : Double;
    var multi:Double;
    var resultado : Double;

    begin
         client :=   TTServerMethodsClient.Create(SQLConnectionDTComprobantes.DBXConnection);
         ds := DBGridDTCompo.DataSource.DataSet;

         if not SQLConnectionDTComprobantes.Connected  then
                SQLConnectionDTComprobantes.Connected := True;



        fecha := ds.FieldByName('fecha').Value;
        numerocompo := ds.FieldByName('numero_comprobante').Value;
        codigo_producto := ds.FieldByName('codigo_producto').Value;
        valor_unitario := ds.FieldByName('valor_unitario').Value;
        canti :=  ds.FieldByName('cantidad').Value;
        eproceso :=  '1';

        try

  //INSERT        label2.Caption:=client.ProcedureSDTComprobantes(strToFloat(canti),codigo_producto,strToDateTime(fecha),numerocompo,strToFloat(valor_unitario),strToInt(eproceso));

        finally
         FreeAndNil(client);
        end;

    end;
```

SQLServer:

```
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[setComprobantes]
@numero_comprobante varchar(12),
@fecha datetime,
@codigo_producto varchar(10),
@cantidad decimal(15, 4),
@valor_unitario decimal(15, 4),
@eproceso int
as
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @variable INT



    SET @variable = (SELECT eproceso FROM detalle_comprobante WHERE eproceso = @eproceso);

    IF @variable=NULL

    INSERT INTO detalle_comprobante (numero_comprobante,fecha,cantidad, codigo_producto,valor_unitario,eproceso) 
    VALUES 
    (@numero_comprobante,@fecha,@cantidad,@codigo_producto,@valor_unitario,@eproceso);

    ELSE
        UPDATE detalle_comprobante
        SET 
            fecha = @fecha,
            codigo_producto =@codigo_producto, 
            cantidad =@cantidad, 
            valor_unitario =@valor_unitario,
            eproceso = @eproceso
            WHERE numero_comprobante=@numero_comprobante

END
```

Script del lado del servidor:

```
function TTServerMethods.ProcedureSDTComprobantes(canti: Double; coditemsd: string; fechas : TDateTime; numcompro:String;  valorUnis:Double;const eproceso : Integer): String;
begin
 try
       if not EjemploDatasnap.Connected then
          EjemploDatasnap.Connected := true;


       if SQLStoredDTComprobantes.Active then
          SQLStoredDTComprobantes.Active := False;


       //SQLStoredDTComprobantes.Open;
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('cantidad').AsString := floatToStr(canti);
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('coditems').AsString := coditemsd;
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('fecha').AsString := DateTimeToStr(fechas);
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('numcompo').AsString := numcompro;
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('valoruni').AsString := floatTostr(valorUnis);
       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.ParamByName('eproceso').AsString := intToStr(eproceso);
       //SQLStoredDTComprobantes.Close;

       SQLStoredDTComprobantes.Active := True;
       //SQLDataSetIProductos.Active:=False;



   except on
   E: Exception do
    Result := E.Message;
end;

end;
```

Comment: Nahuel, para poder ayudarte, considero necesario que nos sitúes un poco más en contexto de la situación, por ejemplo, ¿En la ejecución de qué línea de código salta ese error? ¿el error salta en el cliente? ¿en el servidor?

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar! Jachguate! El error sale cuando ejecuto la consulta insert a la base de datos. Se que el error esta en los "tipos" de datos de los parámetros que le estoy pasando al procedimiento almacenado. La solución (que no es la solución) fue cambiarle los tipo de parámetros a String. El error que ves en la imagen estimo que se debe a algún parámetro de tipo DUBLE. No te sabría decir si esta del lado del cliente o del lado del servidor.

Comment: Si los ejecutas dentro del debugger (F9 desde el IDE de Delphi), podrás determinar fácilmente si el que falla es el servidor, o el cliente. También la línea exacta de código dónde el error se produce.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo un detalle, el SQL tienes en el campo CANTI como DECIMAL que es correcto pero en la declaracion lo tienes como string: Por eso te da el error